# Selenium Webdriver как использовать прокси вида ip:port:log:pass?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

Пытался работать с паблик прокси, но мне нужен аптайм 24/7 и большая скорость. Купил прокси с логпасом, но как их запихнуть я не знаю. Если в коде просто вставить их в место ip:port, то при заходе на 2ip.ru мне скрин показывает, что там айпи не прокси, а мой. Как исправить?
Код ниже

```
( часть выше вставлять не решил, ибо там много мусора )
PROXY = "ip:port:log:pass"

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy']={
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "autodetect":False
}

driver_options = Options()
driver_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'.\chromedriver', options=driver_options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=D:\\qc1.log"])
driver.get('http://2ip.ru')
time.sleep(5)
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть вот этот ответ, там есть альтернтивный способ прописывания прокси: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304253/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-user-password-using-python-selenium/39903614